# How to use curdate() of mysql in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
SELECT `code_id`, `credits` FROM `promotion_codes` WHERE `code`=? AND CURDATE() BETWEEN `start_date` AND `expiry_date` limit 1
```

Is there any solution to execute the same above query in sequelize or an alternate of CURDATE() function in sequelize?

Answer (score 2):

```
PromotionCodes.findAll({
  where: {
    code: code,
    start_date: { lt: Sequelize.fn('CURRDATE') },
    expiry_date: { lt: Sequelize.fn('CURRDATE') }
  },
  limit: 1
});
```

This is not the exact same query since it generates `start_date < CURRDATE() AND end_date > CURRDATE()`, but it should do what you want